# Does the zeroth root exist?

Tags: arithmetic

Definition of $Nth$ root:

$3rd$ order inverse group $1$ hyperoperation.

Division is how many times you can subtract a certain divisor from the dividend before it becomes negative.

Likewise Nth root is the result of repeated division by a certain divisor before it becomes $1$ or a decimal. The number of times you divide it before it becomes a decimal is the index.

Ex: $\sqrt [3]{8} = (8/2)/2$

Is the zeroth root even defined and if so what is $\sqrt [0]{x}$

Comment: $\sqrt[0]{x}$ would be the answer to "Which number, when raised to the zeroth power, becomes $x$?". This is not an answerable question, in any practical interpretation of the word "answerable".

Comment: Actually 1 would satisfy this because 1 to any power is 1. So there is a 0th root of 1.

Comment: @caters So would every other number...

Comment: So $\sqrt[0]{1}$ is indeterminate value, and the zero root of any other number is undefined. Sounds like dividing by zero...

Answer (score 12):

The $n$-th root is the inverse of the operation $x \mapsto x^n$. (Let's take $x>0$ to avoid complications.)

For $n=0$, the operation $x \mapsto x^0$ is not invertible, since it is a constant function.

So, there is no $0$-th root operation.

Answer (score 11):

The $n^\text{th}$ root of a real number $x$ is $$x^{1/n}$$

If $n=0$ then $1/0$ is undefined, so there is no such thing as the $0^{\text{th}}$ root.

Answer (score 3):

No this is usually not defined. One definition of the $n$th root is
$$
\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
So for a fixed $x>1$ you see that 
$$
\lim_{n\to 0^+} x^{\frac{1}{n}} = \infty.
$$

Comment: and there is also the definition of an nth root being repeated division because that is really what you are doing when taking the nth root is you are dividing repeatedly until your next division will lead to 1 or a decimal. Now of course this definition has limited divisors for any x. The divisors that will satisfy this are the factors(prime and composite both) of x.

Comment: @caters : Taking $n^{\text{th}}$ roots has nothing to do with repeated divisions... I don't know where you get this.

Comment: Wikipedia page about hyperoperations says that group 1 inverse hyperoperations are like this: Subtraction, Division, Nth root, Super root

Comment: Now according to this division is repeated subtraction, Nth root is repeated division, and Super root is repeated Nth root since a hyperoperation is an operation that can be or is defined as repeating the previous operation x times.

Answer (score 3):

If we reform this, it could be represented as $X^{\frac{1}{0}}$, so when used in standard functional mathematics, it would be undefined, because $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

However, if used in the calculation of a limit and the function reduces to this form after substitution, I'd think this would be considered an indeterminate form, because not enough information is given to determine the original limit.  It could be any number.  It would end up then looking like $1^\infty$, which would itself be an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt[n]{x}=x^{1/n},$$
if $n=0$ then ...

Comment: x^(1/0) is undefined because dividing by 0 itself is undefined

Comment: @caters Therefore $\sqrt[0]{x}$ isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

We can look for the value of zeroth root of 2 using limits.

Using trusty WolframAlpha to do this for us we arrive at the conclusion that the limit of 2^(1\n) as n approaches 0 is either 0 or infinity depending on the direction from which we arrive to 0 which means that the zeroth root is undefined.

[image: Wolfram]

Comment: If someone can help me with the math code here, it would be great.